# Errors when creating java proxy client

Tags: java, networking, proxy

I am trying to create a web proxy client in java. I stole this guys code and modified it to create a server and now a client so that the user can just download and run the client to connect to the server. I would just like this to run on the terminal but my future plans are to add a gui.

This is the server. This works straight out of the box as in you enter the ip in firefox and it will run just fine. TLDR: It parses the URL and forwards the data from the client to the server and vice versa.

Request Handler.java

```
/*

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
STOLEN FROM THIS MAN ON GITHUB
https://github.com/stefano-lupo/Java-Proxy-Server/blob/master/src/RequestHandler.java

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.imageio.*;

public class RequestHandler implements Runnable {

    /**
     * Socket connected to client passed by Proxy server
     */
    Socket clientSocket;

    /**
     * Read data client sends to proxy
     */
    BufferedReader proxyToClientBr;

    /**
     * Send data from proxy to client
     */
    BufferedWriter proxyToClientBw;


    /**
     * Thread that is used to transmit data read from client to server when using HTTPS
     * Reference to this is required so it can be closed once completed.
     */
    private Thread httpsClientToServer;


    /**
     * Creates a RequestHandler object capable of servicing HTTP(S) GET requests
     * @param clientSocket socket connected to the client
     */
    public RequestHandler(Socket clientSocket){
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        try
        {
            this.clientSocket.setSoTimeout(2000);
            proxyToClientBr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            proxyToClientBw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error on IO Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    /**
     * Reads and examines the requestString and calls the appropriate method based
     * on the request type.
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {

        // Get Request from client
        String requestString;
        try{
            requestString = proxyToClientBr.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error reading request from client");
            return;
        }

        // Parse out URL
        System.out.println("Request Received " + requestString);
        // Get the Request type
        String request = requestString.substring(0,requestString.indexOf(' '));

        // remove request type and space
        String urlString = requestString.substring(requestString.indexOf(' ')+1);

        // Remove everything past next space
        urlString = urlString.substring(0, urlString.indexOf(' '));

        // Prepend http:// if necessary to create correct URL
        if(!urlString.substring(0,4).equals("http")){
            String temp = "http://";
            urlString = temp + urlString;
        }


        // Check request type
        if(request.equals("CONNECT")){
            System.out.println("HTTPS Request for : " + urlString + "\n");
            handleHTTPSRequest(urlString);
        }

        else
    {
            System.out.println("HTTP GET for : " + urlString + "\n");
            sendNonCachedToClient(urlString);

        }
    }
     /**
     * Sends the contents of the file specified by the urlString to the client
     * @param urlString URL ofthe file requested
     */
    private void sendNonCachedToClient(String urlString){

        try{

            // Compute a logical file name as per schema
            // This allows the files on stored on disk to resemble that of the URL it was taken from
            int fileExtensionIndex = urlString.lastIndexOf(".");
            String fileExtension;

            // Get the type of file
            fileExtension = urlString.substring(fileExtensionIndex, urlString.length());

            // Get the initial file name
            String fileName = urlString.substring(0,fileExtensionIndex);


            // Trim off http://www. as no need for it in file name
            fileName = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf('.')+1);

            // Remove any illegal characters from file name
            fileName = fileName.replace("/", "__");
            fileName = fileName.replace('.','_');

            // Trailing / result in index.html of that directory being fetched
            if(fileExtension.contains("/")){
                fileExtension = fileExtension.replace("/", "__");
                fileExtension = fileExtension.replace('.','_');
                fileExtension += ".html";
            }

            fileName = fileName + fileExtension;



            // Attempt to create File to cache to
            boolean caching = true;
            File fileToCache = null;
            BufferedWriter fileToCacheBW = null;

            try{
                // Create File to cache
                fileToCache = new File("cached/" + fileName);

                if(!fileToCache.exists()){
                    fileToCache.createNewFile();
                }

                // Create Buffered output stream to write to cached copy of file
                fileToCacheBW = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileToCache));
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println("Couldn't cache: " + fileName);
                caching = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                System.out.println("NPE opening file");
            }





            // Check if file is an image
            if((fileExtension.contains(".png")) || fileExtension.contains(".jpg") ||
                    fileExtension.contains(".jpeg") || fileExtension.contains(".gif")){
                // Create the URL
                URL remoteURL = new URL(urlString);
                BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(remoteURL);

                if(image != null) {
                    // Cache the image to disk
                    ImageIO.write(image, fileExtension.substring(1), fileToCache);

                    // Send response code to client
                    String line = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n" +
                            "Proxy-agent: ProxyServer/1.0\n" +
                            "\r\n";
                    proxyToClientBw.write(line);
                    proxyToClientBw.flush();

                    // Send them the image data
                    ImageIO.write(image, fileExtension.substring(1), clientSocket.getOutputStream());

                // No image received from remote server
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Sending 404 to client as image wasn't received from server"
                            + fileName);
                    String error = "HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND\n" +
                            "Proxy-agent: ProxyServer/1.0\n" +
                            "\r\n";
                    proxyToClientBw.write(error);
                    proxyToClientBw.flush();
                    return;
                }
            }

            // File is a text file
            else {

                // Create the URL
                URL remoteURL = new URL(urlString);
                // Create a connection to remote server
                HttpURLConnection proxyToServerCon = (HttpURLConnection)remoteURL.openConnection();
                proxyToServerCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                proxyToServerCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
                proxyToServerCon.setUseCaches(false);
                proxyToServerCon.setDoOutput(true);

                // Create Buffered Reader from remote Server
                BufferedReader proxyToServerBR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proxyToServerCon.getInputStream()));


                // Send success code to client
                String line = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n" +
                        "Proxy-agent: ProxyServer/1.0\n" +
                        "\r\n";
                proxyToClientBw.write(line);


                // Read from input stream between proxy and remote server
                while((line = proxyToServerBR.readLine()) != null){
                    // Send on data to client
                    proxyToClientBw.write(line);

                    // Write to our cached copy of the file
                    if(caching){
                        fileToCacheBW.write(line);
                    }
                }

                // Ensure all data is sent by this point
                proxyToClientBw.flush();

                // Close Down Resources
                if(proxyToServerBR != null){
                    proxyToServerBR.close();
                }
            }


            // Close down resources
            if(fileToCacheBW != null){
                fileToCacheBW.close();
            }

            if(proxyToClientBw != null){
                proxyToClientBw.close();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Handles HTTPS requests between client and remote server
     * @param urlString desired file to be transmitted over https
     */
    private void handleHTTPSRequest(String urlString){
        // Extract the URL and port of remote
        String url = urlString.substring(7);
        String pieces[] = url.split(":");
        url = pieces[0];
        int port  = Integer.valueOf(pieces[1]);

        try{
            // Only first line of HTTPS request has been read at this point (CONNECT *)
            // Read (and throw away) the rest of the initial data on the stream
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                proxyToClientBr.readLine();
            }

            // Get actual IP associated with this URL through DNS
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(url);

            // Open a socket to the remote server
            Socket proxyToServerSocket = new Socket(address, port);
            proxyToServerSocket.setSoTimeout(5000);

            // Send Connection established to the client
            String line = "HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established\r\n" +
                    "Proxy-Agent: ProxyServer/1.0\r\n" +
                    "\r\n";
            proxyToClientBw.write(line);
            proxyToClientBw.flush();



            // Client and Remote will both start sending data to proxy at this point
            // Proxy needs to asynchronously read data from each party and send it to the other party


            //Create a Buffered Writer betwen proxy and remote
            BufferedWriter proxyToServerBW = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(proxyToServerSocket.getOutputStream()));

            // Create Buffered Reader from proxy and remote
            BufferedReader proxyToServerBR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proxyToServerSocket.getInputStream()));



            // Create a new thread to listen to client and transmit to server
            ClientToServerHttpsTransmit clientToServerHttps =
                    new ClientToServerHttpsTransmit(clientSocket.getInputStream(), proxyToServerSocket.getOutputStream());

            httpsClientToServer = new Thread(clientToServerHttps);
            httpsClientToServer.start();


            // Listen to remote server and relay to client
            try {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int read;
                do {
                    read = proxyToServerSocket.getInputStream().read(buffer);
                    if (read > 0) {
                        clientSocket.getOutputStream().write(buffer, 0, read);
                        if (proxyToServerSocket.getInputStream().available() < 1) {
                            clientSocket.getOutputStream().flush();
                        }
                    }
                } while (read >= 0);
            }
            catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {

            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            // Close Down Resources
            if(proxyToServerSocket != null){
                proxyToServerSocket.close();
            }

            if(proxyToServerBR != null){
                proxyToServerBR.close();
            }

            if(proxyToServerBW != null){
                proxyToServerBW.close();
            }

            if(proxyToClientBw != null){
                proxyToClientBw.close();
            }


        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            String line = "HTTP/1.0 504 Timeout Occured after 10s\n" +
                    "User-Agent: ProxyServer/1.0\n" +
                    "\r\n";
            try{
                proxyToClientBw.write(line);
                proxyToClientBw.flush();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error on HTTPS : " + urlString );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




    /**
     * Listen to data from client and transmits it to server.
     * This is done on a separate thread as must be done
     * asynchronously to reading data from server and transmitting
     * that data to the client.
     */
    class ClientToServerHttpsTransmit implements Runnable{

        InputStream proxyToClientIS;
        OutputStream proxyToServerOS;

        /**
         * Creates Object to Listen to Client and Transmit that data to the server
         * @param proxyToClientIS Stream that proxy uses to receive data from client
         * @param proxyToServerOS Stream that proxy uses to transmit data to remote server
         */
        public ClientToServerHttpsTransmit(InputStream proxyToClientIS, OutputStream proxyToServerOS) {
            this.proxyToClientIS = proxyToClientIS;
            this.proxyToServerOS = proxyToServerOS;
        }

        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {
                // Read byte by byte from client and send directly to server
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int read;
                do {
                    read = proxyToClientIS.read(buffer);
                    if (read > 0) {
                        proxyToServerOS.write(buffer, 0, read);
                        if (proxyToClientIS.available() < 1) {
                            proxyToServerOS.flush();
                        }
                    }
                } while (read >= 0);
            }
            catch (SocketTimeoutException ste)
            {
                ste.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Proxy to client HTTPS read timed out");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the client. It doesn't seem to work and I dont really understand why as it is just a modified version of the server.

Request Handler.java

```
/*

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
STOLEN FROM THIS MAN ON GITHUB
https://github.com/stefano-lupo/Java-Proxy-Server/blob/master/src/RequestHandler.java

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.imageio.*;

public class RequestHandler implements Runnable
{

    /**
     * Socket connected to client passed by Proxy server
     */
    Socket clientSocket;

    /**
     * Read data client sends to proxy
     */
    BufferedReader clientToClientBr;

    /**
     * Send data from proxy to client
     */
    BufferedWriter clientToClientBw;


    /**
     * Thread that is used to transmit data read from client to server when using HTTPS
     * Reference to this is required so it can be closed once completed.
     */
    private Thread threads;


    /**
     * Creates a RequestHandler object capable of servicing HTTP(S) GET requests
     * @param clientSocket socket connected to the client
     */
    public RequestHandler(Socket clientSocket)
  {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        try
        {
            this.clientSocket.setSoTimeout(2000);
            clientToClientBr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            clientToClientBw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error on IO Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reads and examines the requestString and calls the appropriate method based
     * on the request type.
     */
    @Override
    public void run()
  {

        // Get Request from client
        String requestString;
        try
    {
            requestString = clientToClientBr.readLine();
      System.out.println(requestString);
      sendToServer(requestString);

        }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error reading request from client");
            return;
        }
    }

    private void sendToServer(String urlString) throws IOException
  {

            // Open a socket to the remote server
            Socket proxyToServerSocket = new Socket("192.168.0.226", 8080);
            proxyToServerSocket.setSoTimeout(5000);


            // Client and Remote will both start sending data to proxy at this point
            // Proxy needs to asynchronously read data from each party and send it to the other party


            //Create a Buffered Writer betwen proxy and remote
            BufferedWriter proxyToServerBW = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(proxyToServerSocket.getOutputStream()));

            // Create Buffered Reader from proxy and remote
            BufferedReader proxyToServerBR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proxyToServerSocket.getInputStream()));



            // Create a new thread to listen to client and transmit to server
            ClientToServerHttpsTransmit clientToServerHttps = new ClientToServerHttpsTransmit(clientSocket.getInputStream(), proxyToServerSocket.getOutputStream());

            threads = new Thread(clientToServerHttps);
            threads.start();


            // Listen to remote server and relay to client
            try {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int read;
                do
        {
                    read = proxyToServerSocket.getInputStream().read(buffer);
                    if (read > 0)
          {
                        clientSocket.getOutputStream().write(buffer, 0, read);
                        if (proxyToServerSocket.getInputStream().available() < 1)
            {
                            clientSocket.getOutputStream().flush();
                        }
                    }
                } while (read >= 0);
            }
            catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {

            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            // Close Down Resources
            if(proxyToServerSocket != null){
                proxyToServerSocket.close();
            }

            if(proxyToServerBR != null){
                proxyToServerBR.close();
            }

            if(proxyToServerBW != null){
                proxyToServerBW.close();
            }

            if(clientToClientBw != null){
                clientToClientBw.close();
            }


        }
    }




    /**
     * Listen to data from client and transmits it to server.
     * This is done on a separate thread as must be done
     * asynchronously to reading data from server and transmitting
     * that data to the client.
     */
    class ClientToServerHttpsTransmit implements Runnable
  {

        InputStream proxyToClientIS;
        OutputStream proxyToServerOS;

        /**
         * Creates Object to Listen to Client and Transmit that data to the server
         * @param proxyToClientIS Stream that proxy uses to receive data from client
         * @param proxyToServerOS Stream that proxy uses to transmit data to remote server
         */
        public ClientToServerHttpsTransmit(InputStream proxyToClientIS, OutputStream proxyToServerOS)
    {
            this.proxyToClientIS = proxyToClientIS;
            this.proxyToServerOS = proxyToServerOS;
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
    {
            try
      {
                // Read byte by byte from client and send directly to server
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int read;
                do
        {
                    read = proxyToClientIS.read(buffer);
                    if (read > 0)
          {
                        proxyToServerOS.write(buffer, 0, read);
                        if (proxyToClientIS.available() < 1)
            {
                            proxyToServerOS.flush();
                        }
                    }
                } while (read >= 0);
            }
            catch (SocketTimeoutException ste)
            {
                ste.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
      {
                System.out.println("Proxy to client HTTPS read timed out");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I think that the error is in the Request Handler for the Client as the error message I get on the client terminal is:

```
Wating for client to connect on port 8080
Got CONNECT www.youtube.com:443 HTTP/1.1
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:127)
    at ClientToServerHttpsTransmit.run(RequestHandler.java:186)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

and this is the error for the terminal on the server:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at RequestHandler.run(RequestHandler.java:75)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Error reading request from client
```

Comment: That's a _lot_ of code, you might want to look at trying to extract some of the information to form a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Tom I condensed it down to just the two request handlers